# Owl Carousel inside a table-cell parent makes parent to expand weird

Tags: jquery, css

```
<section class='parent' style='display: table-cell;'>
//<div class='enclose'>
<div class='child'></div>
<div class='child'></div>
<div class='child'></div>
<div class='child'></div>
//</div><!--enclose-->
</section><!--parent-->
```

JS:

```
<script>
$('.parent').owlCarousel(); // without children enclosure div
//$('.enclose').owlCarousel(); // If children are enclosed inside a block-div
</script>
```

Now `<div class='parent'>` expands around 10000 to 20000 pixels in width depends up on number of the children inside. On inspection I understood that the [owlCarousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/) `<div>` sets width depending on the number of items. And since the parent is set to `table-cell` display style, that too expands. So I just added another `<div>` to encode the children and set it's display property as `block`. But this too doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: you need to give you `div.enclose` a class of `owl-carousel` so it works with the style sheet (it has some styles that it needs to apply so the inner divs that get created work properly)

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution for this, keeping the table-cell property?

Answer (score 14):

I tend to use and reuse this markup a lot in my projects:

```
<div class="display_table">

    <div class="display_tablerow">

        <div style="display:table-cell;" class="parent display_tablecell"></div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Paired up with the following CSS:

```
.display_table {  
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}
.display_tablerow {    
    width: 100%;
    display: table-row;
}
.display_tablecell {

    display: table-cell;
}
```

Given I encountered the same issue as you did, I managed to solve the problem by simply adding "table-layout: fixed;" to the previous display_table css:

```
.display_table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```